# Invalid credentials after installing Linkedin's WhereHows

Tags: linkedin-api

After installing Linkedin's `WhereHows` accoring to the github docs (https://github.com/linkedin/WhereHows/blob/master/wherehows-docs/getting-started.md#getting-started), am finding that I cannot sign into the login screen where `wherehows` complains that the credentials are invalid (using some LDAP user)
[image]

Does anyone know what is going on with this?

** My configuration variables for the `Play` frontend (https://github.com/linkedin/WhereHows/blob/master/wherehows-docs/getting-started.md#frontend-setup) look like:

```
export WHZ_DB_USERNAME="wherehows"
export WHZ_DB_PASSWORD="wherehows"
export WHZ_DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/wherehows"

export WHZ_ES_DATASET_URL="localhost:9200/wherehows"
export WHZ_ES_METRIC_URL="localhost:9200/_nodes/stats"
export WHZ_ES_FLOW_URL="localhost:9200/wherehows/flows_jobs"

export YOUR_HDFS_BROWSER_LINK="http://node004.myco.local:8888/filebrowser/#"

export WHZ_LDAP_URL="ldap://co.myco.local:389"
export WHZ_LDAP_PRINCIPAL_DOMAIN="@co.local"
export WHZ_LDAP_SEARCH_BASE="ou=mapr access,dc=co,dc=local"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a hint from this github post (https://github.com/linkedin/WhereHows/issues/874#issuecomment-346031871), it appears that `wherehows` looks for valid users in the database backend (see https://github.com/linkedin/WhereHows/blob/master/wherehows-docs/getting-started.md#database-setup) `wherehows.users`.

So doing something like

```
> [me@mapr07 wherehows-frontend]$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 231
Server version: 5.6.40 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select * from wherehows.users;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO wherehows.users 
    (name, email, username, password_digest, password_digest_type, authentication_type) 
    VALUES ('testuser', 'rvillanueva@ucera.org', 'testuser', SHA1('testuser'), 'SHA1', 'default');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> exit
```

We can then sign into the `wherehows` login screen with name=testuser and password=testuser.

**Though this does leave me a bit confused on where exactly LDAP then comes into the picture if the only thing that seems to matter is the existence of the user on the sql backend that was set up as part of the installation (if anyone knows the answer to this please let me know).

**Update**:
It appears that this is only a known *workaround* and that users *should* be able to use LDAP (https://github.com/linkedin/WhereHows/issues/616#issuecomment-323164744), so this answer could be improved by investigating the root cause of the problem of not being able to use LDAP credentials on the login screen.